# Boost Asio Synchoronous https call

Tags: c++, ssl, https, boost-asio, pyopenssl

I am using the below code to make https synchoronous call with ssl certificate validation. As part of sanity testing, I am trying to hit the https url wihout ssl validations and used the below code but i could see that its not writing POST method into socket. Am i missing anything here and how we need to get the client certificates to hit https url to include it here?

```
 try{
       boost::asio::streambuf request_;       
        boost::asio::streambuf response_;

        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
        //ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
        //ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");
        ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3);

        boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(io_service,ctx);

        std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
        //request_stream << "POST /v4/decisionset/entitlements" << " HTTP/1.1\n";
        request_stream << "POST " << server_endpoint << " HTTP/1.1\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << hostname << "\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\n";
        request_stream << authorization_token << "\n";
        request_stream << client_name << "\n";
        request_stream << "Content-Length: " << req_str.length() << "\n";
        request_stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        request_stream << req_str << "\n";
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(hostname, port_no);

        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;


        boost::asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator);
        boost::asio::write(socket, request_);


        // Read the response status line.
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response_, "\r\n");
        string res=make_string(response_);
}
```

Comment: Headers should end in `\r\n` not `\n`

Comment: i can able to hit https url after disabling the ssl validation part and am missed handshake here..Please let me know how we need to get client certificates and how to include it here.